# Apple pay merchant id in Apple Wallet - can it be updated dynamically?

Tags: ios, applepay, passkit

Our iOS App provides on line ordering capability to various merchants who are part of our network. We want to create unique merchant identifier and matching certificate for each merchant. My question is this: Can we update the Apple Wallet dynamically with new merchant IDs thru appropriate web service from the App to our server? Or do we need to create all the IDs before we release the App?

Answer (score 2):

Since your merchant identifier(s) is/are signed into your app through an entitlement you can't update them dynamically. They wouldn't match the entitlement that was signed into your app when you compiled it.